# CSS Dropdown Menubar & Header flickers only on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I am so stumped by this one:

http://www.jessewilliamson.ca/showlisting/99039/1317-Civic-Place-Mews-Central-Lonsdale-North-Vancouver-north-shore-realtor

On that site, ONLY when you are viewing a property detail page, there's a flicker on the top when you hover over the "FEATURED LISTINGS" tab on the top nav, and only on Safari. on Chrome & FF it works fine (I'm on a mac). I haven't even tested on IE just yet.

Any clues? What could possibly be doing that?

Also note that there's another dropdown under "RESOURCES" but hovering over that does NOT trigger the same error. I'm totally stumped.

Comment: Post the relevant code.  http://sscce.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that using `left:-9999px` and `left:-5px` to show the submenu on hover is causing the problem.

Maybe try playing with `visibility` instead?

For example :

```
#menu .submenu {
    position:absolute;   
    display: block;
    background-color:#1175A6;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    top:15px;
    z-index: 20;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
#menu li:hover .submenu {
    left: -5px;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Tested in Safari and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Weird - that dropdown method has worked for me forever with all sorts of sites. It did fix it - now testing on IE to make sure it's consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I am also on a mac, fo me it flickers also on each item that has a submenu that appears on :hover... can you post some code how you did the drop-down menu?